# Toast se um componente ganhar foco

Tags: android, google-maps

Quero exibir um toast se o map view ganhar foco. O que consegui fazer até agora foi:

```
        mapView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tem o foco", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Mas ao que parece, somente rolar a tela não dá o foco ao componente. Como proceder?

Comment: O que quer saber exactamente?

Comment: Ao rolar a tela e o usuário ver o mapview, mostrar um toast